# Building and Publishing on Azure Devops Failed

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, web-config

I wanted to publish my project in Azure Devops pipeline but I encountered several errors.

I tried to publish one of the .csproj file of my solution (.sln) from VisualStudio2017 it worked perfectly  but when I try it with Azure Devops pipeline then it shows the below error. I've googled everywhere but not able to find the correct solution to solve my error.

[My pipeline looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR6y7.png)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Node.js Tools\Microsoft.NodejsTools.targets(201,5): Error : web.config not found in project, to create a project to deploy to Microsoft Azure you must create an Azure Node.js project. Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'
```

Tried adding the basic web.config file even that doesn't work.

Comment: From the error I understand you have a NodeJS project? I think such information should be represented in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Building and Publishing on Azure Devops Failed

To resolve this issue, you can try a quick way to solve it is by creating a Blank `Azure Node.js` Web Application and copy-paste the `web.config` into your project.

Check more details on section "Converting to an Azure project type" of page: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Publish-to-Azure-Website-using-Web-Deploy:

> The easiest way to get them is to create a new temporary Azure project
>   type, such as:
>
> Blank Azure Node.js Web Application Basic Azure Node.js Express
>   Application Starter Azure Node.js Express Application Basic Azure
>   Node.js Express 4 Application And copy the missing web.config and bin
>   folder from the new project to your existing project.
>
> Note that in web.config, the starter .js file (app.js, server.js or
>   something else) appears a few times. Make sure that it matches your
>   starter file, otherwise your application won't run properly when it's
>   deployed on Azure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I resolved it in some other way, I added web.config file and included in my node.js  project and it works perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete delete and create a new solution or override the existing solution.
Then build it locally and then, check-in & build in azure CI pipeline.
It worked for me hope it works for you too.